# TypeError: stream_get_listen_key() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, binance

I am trying to run 2 websockets at the same time using python-binance.

```
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager
from binance.client import Client
client = Client('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
bm = BinanceSocketManager(Client)
def process_m_message(msg):
    print('message 1')

def process_message(msg):
    print('message 2')

conn_key = bm.start_multiplex_socket(['!ticker@arr'], process_m_message)
bm.start_user_socket(process_message)
bm.start()
```

The multiplex socket works on it's own but I can't figure out how to get the user socket working. In the research that I've done it seems like leaving out `bm = BinanceSocketManager(Client)` would cause my error but I have it in my code already.

Comment: Looks like you need lowercase `client` there.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you!